# Setting JTextField font to what is selected in JFontChooser

Tags: java, swing, fonts

I found this component recently and its great exactly what I wanted but I am unsure how to use it.

How would I set the font of my `JTextField` to what is selected by the user in the `JFontChooser`?

This is all I can find on it:

> The `JFontChooser` class is a swing component for font selection. This class has `JFileChooser` like APIs. The following code pops up a font chooser dialog.

```
JFontChooser fontChooser = new JFontChooser();
int result = fontChooser.showDialog(parent);
if (result == JFontChooser.OK_OPTION)
{
  Font font = fontChooser.getSelectedFont(); 
  System.out.println("Selected Font : " + font); 
}
```

what I want it to do is:

update: `tNumber.setFont(new font(""Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 300));`

To what ever the user has chosen for the font style and size in font chooser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `font.deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 300f)` to create a new font, based on the current font with the properties you supply.

```
tNumber.setFont(font.deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 300f));
```

See [`Font#deriveFont(float, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#deriveFont(int,%20float)) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Well you were very close,

```
JFontChooser fontChooser = new JFontChooser();
int result = fontChooser.showDialog(parent);
if (result == JFontChooser.OK_OPTION)
{
  Font font = fontChooser.getSelectedFont(); 
  tNumber.setFont(font.deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 300f));//This is the line I added.
}
```

See [`setFont`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html#setFont(java.awt.Font)) and [`deriveFont`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#deriveFont(int,%20float)) documentation.

Comment: Beware, unless the font size has been set, it will automatically be set to `1`

Comment: @AjayWard You are not stupid, you are learning. We all learn everyday.